# What is the best way to extract a diagonal from a matrix in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, matrix

I was asked to write a function that would extract the diagonal of a matrix stored as a list of lists. The first version was to extract the number by indexing the lists, but I soon concluded it isn't a good algorithm for Haskell and wrote another function:

```
getDiagonal :: (Num a) => [[a]] -> [a]
getDiagonal [[]]       = []
getDiagonal (xs:[])    = [head xs]
getDiagonal (x:xs)     = head x : getDiagonal (map tail xs)
```

Since I've only started learning Haskell I'm not sure if it's written in an idiomatic way or if it would perform well.

So my question is is there any better way to extract a diagonal from matrix stored in such a representation or if there isn't is there a better algorithm that could be constructed if the matrix was represented using higher order Haskell concepts, like algebraic types?
Also is there any performance difference between deconstructing the list in pattern matching like so ((x:_):xs) or with the head function like shown above?

EDIT: Actually more of curious inquiry than a homework, they don't teach functional programming at technical universities here (which is a pitty I think), but I'll leave the tag.

Comment: Actually, that is pretty much what I'd have written.  Bonus marks for realising that indexing into a list is usually the Wrong Thing.

Comment: I don't think indexing and this scheme will really be worse, as the number of operations is the same. I haven't tested this though, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simplify your original definition to:

```
mainDiagonal :: [[a]] -> [a]
mainDiagonal []     = []
mainDiagonal (x:xs) = head x : getDiagonal (map tail xs)
```

There isn't much wrong with using indexing for this, which lets you simplify it further to:

```
mainDiagonal xs = zipWith (!!) xs [0..]
```

### Array-based representation

You can also represent matrixes using [Data.Array](http://users.skynet.be/jyp/html/base/Data-Array.html) indexed by `(i,j)`. This lets you use the mathematical definition of the main diagonal almost verbatim:

```
import Data.Array

mainDiagonal :: (Ix i) => Array (i, i) e -> [e]
mainDiagonal xs = [ e | ((i,j),e) <- assocs xs, i == j ]
```

You can use this like:

```
-- n×n matrix helper
matrix n = listArray ((0,0),(n-1,n-1))

> mainDiagonal $ matrix 3 [1..]
[1,5,9]
```

### Efficiency

The previous definition of `mainDiagonal` is still not efficient: it still needs O(N²) tests of `i == j`. Analogous to the `zipWith` version, it can be fixed and generalized as follows:

```
mainDiagonal xs = (xs !) `map` zip [n..n'] [m..m']
                      where ((n,m),(n',m')) = bounds xs
```

This version only indexes the array O(N) times. (As a bonus, it also works with rectangular matrices, and is independent of the indexing base.)

Comment: So Data.Array is pretty much like a vanilla C array and should thusly be faster than list of lists implementation?

Comment: Data.Array is not exactly like a vanilla C array. First, it is immutable, so while indexing is fast, all mutation operations require a full copy. Second, it holds boxed, possibly unevaluated, values, rather than raw unboxed things. So you can think of it as, roughly, a read-only array of pointers (ish).

Comment: I should add that there are plenty of other Arrays with different characteristics as well, including in particular various combinations of unboxed and mutable, as well as other libraries with different/better approaches depending on your problem domain.

Comment: Jaen: In general, array indexing is O(1) instead of O(N), yes. For this problem, it only helps if you *use* that indexing, though: i've annotated my answer with an O(N) indexing version to go with the naive O(N²) definition.

Comment: Alternative version: `mainDiagonal xs = zipWith (uncurry (xs !)) [n..n'] [m..m'] where...`

Comment: I think I'd go with this answer as the accepted one as it's the more comprehensive; thank you both though.

Answer (score 21):

I think using indexing is OK, if you can assume that the argument is a square matrix. Getting diagonal with this representation is O(N<sup>2</sup>) anyway, since you have to traverse the lists.

```
diag x = zipWith (!!) x [0..]
```

Comment: Wow, as far as this representation goes this really is pretty neat.

Comment: The point of tagging something as "homework" is (to me, at least) that you should provide more explanation than code. An answer is incomplete if it gives code (or at least clever code like this) without explaining how it works. I'd like to see an expansion of how `zipWith` combines the `!!` function with the elements of `x` and `[0..]` to provide the result.

Comment: @Gabe: The poster said this is not a homework; I believe that. I think it's more instructive for the reader to comprehend the definition himself, than to give a "spoonfeeding" explanation.

Comment: Actually this definition is pretty much straightforward to understand for me, though it may have additional merit to explain it for others who may come across this question.

Answer (score 5):

sdcwc has answered the original question. I'd like to note that representing the matrix as a list of lists is usually inefficient. Lists are good where the length is unknown, matrices are usually of the fixed size. You may consider using a flat associative list or map to build the matrix, and anything with constant element access time when you actually run calculations with this matrix. `Data.Array` is a good choice (see Piet's answer).

If you run numerical calculations in Haskell, you can use `hmatrix` package. It has its own matrix data type, [`Data.Packed.Matrix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.10.0.0/doc/html/Data-Packed-Matrix.html), and it has a `takeDiag` function to extract the diagonal.

### Data.Packed.Matrix example

For example, if `m` is your matrix

```
ghci> let m = (3><3) [1..]
ghci> :t m
m :: Matrix Double
ghci> m
(3><3)
 [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0
 , 4.0, 5.0, 6.0
 , 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 ]
```

then you can extract its diagonal like this:

```
ghci> takeDiag m
3 |> [1.0,5.0,9.0]
```

Comment: I gather this is a wrapper for some low level matrix library?

Comment: Hmatrix can be compiled to use `Data.Vector.Storable` (build it with `-fvector` flag). By default it uses its own implementation of the vectors (also to represent matrices).

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing Delport's answer a little bit, if performance is not that relevant and you choose this approach:

```hs
diagonal :: [[a]] -> [a]
diagonal [] = []
diagonal (mHead:mTail) = head mHead:diagonal (map tail mTail)
```

It should be noted that this function can only be used with matrices you know are square, due to `head` and `tail` usage.

For `n X m` matrices you can either implement the function to ignore extra values, making `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` return `[1,5]`:

```hs
diagonal [] = []
diagonal ([]:_) = []
diagonal ((rHead:_):mTail) = rHead:diagonal (map tail mTail)
```

Or implement a version that will throw an error when your matrix is not square:

```hs
diagonal [] = []
diagonal ([]:_) = error "not a square matrix"
diagonal [x:y:z] = error "not a square matrix"
diagonal ((rHead:_):mTail) = rHead:diagonal (map tail mTail)
```

For both answers, it should be noted that they might still throw 'unexpected' errors if your 'list of lists' is not a matrix/not uniform (`[[1,2], [1]]`) due to the `map tail mTail` call.