# Getting all the diagonals of a matrix in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix

The two-dimensional list looks like:

```
1 | 2 | 3
- - - - -
4 | 5 | 6
- - - - -
7 | 8 | 9
```

Or in pure haskell

```
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
```

The expected output for `diagonals [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]` is

```
[ [1], [4, 2], [7, 5, 3], [8, 6], [9] ]
```

Writing `allDiagonals` (to include anti-diagonals) is then trivial:

```
allDiagonals :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
allDiagonals xss = (diagonals xss) ++ (diagonals (rotate90 xss))
```

## My research on this problem

**Similar question here at StackOverflow**

- [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313308/get-all-the-diagonals-in-a-matrix-list-of-lists-in-python) this question is about the same problem in Python, but Python and Haskell are very different, so the answers to that question are not relevant to me.
- [Only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998891/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-a-diagonal-from-a-matrix-in-haskell) This question and answer are in Haskell, but are only about the central diagonal.

**Hoogle**

Searching for `[[a]] -> [[a]]` gave me no interesting result.

**Independent thinking**

I think the the indexing follows a kind of count in base x where x is the number of dimensions in the matrix, look at:

```
1 | 2
- - -
3 | 4
```

The diagonals are `[ [1], [3, 2], [4] ]`

- `1` can be found at `matrix[0][0]`
- `3` can be found at `matrix[1][0]`
- `2` can be found at `matrix[0][1]`
- `1` can be found at `matrix[1][1]`

That is similar to counting in base 2 up to 3, that is the matrix size minus one. But this is far too vague to be translated into code.

Comment: A more natural way of thinking for Haskell is: given the first row and the result of `diagonals` on the matrix consisting of the rest of the rows, how can we construct the result of `diagonals` on the entire original matrix?

Comment: Math for it http://math.stackexchange.com/a/22396/5889

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting with [universe-base-1.0.2.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0.2.1), you may simply call the [`diagonals`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:diagonals) function:

```
Data.Universe.Helpers> diagonals [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
[[1],[4,2],[7,5,3],[8,6],[9]]
```

The implementation in full looks like this:

```
diagonals :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
diagonals = tail . go [] where
    -- it is critical for some applications that we start producing answers
    -- before inspecting es_
    go b es_ = [h | h:_ <- b] : case es_ of
        []   -> transpose ts
        e:es -> go (e:ts) es
        where ts = [t | _:t <- b]
```

The key idea is that we keep two lists: a rectangular chunk we haven't started inspecting, and a pentagonal chunk (a rectangle with the top left triangle cut out!) that we have. For the pentagonal chunk, picking out the first element from each list gives us another diagonal. Then we can add a fresh row from the rectangular, un-inspected chunk to what's left after we delete that diagonal.

The implementation may look a bit unnatural, but it's intended to be quite efficient and lazy: the only thing we do to lists is destructure them into a head and tail, so this should be O(n) in the total number of elements in the matrix; and we produce elements as soon as we finish the destructuring, so it's quite lazy/friendly to garbage collection. It also works well with infinitely large matrices.

(I pushed this release just for you: the previous closest thing you could get was using `diagonal`, which would only give you `[1,4,2,7,5,3,8,6,9]` without the extra structure you want.)

Comment: Is the use of `tail` essential in some way?

Comment: @dfeuer Not essential; but it doesn't seem terribly useful to always start with an empty list.

Comment: is there some other way to skip it?

Comment: @dfeuer Almost certainly! What have you got in mind?

Comment: I just don't like using partial functions to implement total ones unless laziness demands it. In this case, I'm guessing you can treat the first step specially to avoid it, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @dfeuer You could certainly "unroll" the loop one step to avoid using `tail`. In this case, I think the totality argument is local enough (we call `tail` on `go`, which always starts with `(:)`) that it's reasonable to avoid repeating code in the way I did here. Another alternative would be to use `drop 1` in place of `tail`; perhaps if I had thought of it at the time I wrote this I would have, though I'm not sure it warrants effort to change it now.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a recursive version, assuming that the input is always well-formed:

```
diagonals []       = []
diagonals ([]:xss) = xss
diagonals xss      = zipWith (++) (map ((:[]) . head) xss ++ repeat [])
                                  ([]:(diagonals (map tail xss)))
```

It works recursively, going from column to column. The values from one column are combined with the diagonals from the matrix reduced by one column, shifted by one row to actually get the diagonals. Hope this explanation makes sense.

For illustration:

```
diagonals [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
= zipWith (++) [[1],[4],[7],[],[],...] [[],[2],[5,3],[8,6],[9]]
= [[1],[4,2],[7,5,3],[8,6],[9]]
```

Another version that works on the rows instead of the columns, but based on the same idea:

```
diagonals []       = repeat []
diagonals (xs:xss) = takeWhile (not . null) $
    zipWith (++) (map (:[]) xs ++ repeat [])
                 ([]:diagonals xss)
```

Compared to the specified result, the resulting diagonals are reversed. This can of course be fixed by applying `map reverse`.

Answer (score 5):

```
import Data.List

rotate90 = reverse . transpose
rotate180 = rotate90 . rotate90

diagonals = (++) <$> transpose . zipWith drop [0..]
                 <*> transpose . zipWith drop [1..] . rotate180
```

It first gets the main (`[1,5,9]`) and upper diagonals (`[2,6]` and `[3]`); then the lower diagonals: `[8,4]` and `[7]`.

If you care about ordering (i.e. you think it should say `[4,8]` instead of `[8,4]`), insert a `map reverse .` on the last line.

Comment: I actually do not care about ordering

Comment: `rotate180` seems a bit odd. Won't `map reverse . reverse` do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

One another solution:

```
diagonals = map concat
          . transpose
          . zipWith (\ns xs -> ns ++ map (:[]) xs)
                    (iterate ([]:) [])
```

Basically, we turn

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

into

```
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[] , [4], [5], [6]]
[[] , [] , [7], [8], [9]]
```

then `transpose` and `concat` lists. Diagonals are in the reversed order.

But that's not very efficient and doesn't work for infinite lists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach:

```
f :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
f vals = 
    let n = length vals
    in [[(vals !! y) !! x | x <- [0..(n - 1)], 
                            y <- [0..(n - 1)], 
                            x + y == k] 
        | k <- [0 .. 2*(n-1)]]
```

For example, using it in GHCi:

```
Prelude> let f vals = [ [(vals !! y) !! x | x <- [0..(length vals) - 1], y <- [0..(length vals) - 1], x + y == k] | k <- [0 .. 2*((length vals) - 1)]]

Prelude> f [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
[[1],[4,2],[7,5,3],[8,6],[9]]
```

Assuming a square `n` x `n` matrix, there will be `n + n - 1` diagonals (this is what `k` iterates over) and for each diagonal, the invariant is that the row and column index sum to the diagonal value (starting with a zero index for the upper left). You can swap the item access order (swap `!! y !! x` with `!! x !! y`) to reverse the raster scanning order over the matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I am impressed by the speed and clarity of this response. But please rename `f` to `diagonals` as Haskell already has enough single letter names ;P

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to say that I don't like this solution. First, there are too many `!!`, which should be avoided as much as possible on lists (unlike on vectors). Second, it loops over `y<-[0..n-1]` only to find a solution to `x+y==k`, which has a very simple closed form. Third, the complexity of the solution should be stated. While one would hope a O(n^2) solution, the above looks O(n^5) to me.